# How to create a MySql Job to create a database backup and a maintenace plan?

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

How can I create a MySql Job that runs daily to generate a database backup and stores in on the server?

Also How can I create a second Job that does a maintenance on the database to keep it running without problem?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on `mysqldump` and `mysqlcheck`. Create a script and schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is run the following as daily cron.

```
mysqldump -u <db_user> -p <db_password> <db_name> -h <db_host_if_any> > /home/backups/backup_<timestamp>.sql
```

gzip it and store it(just a mechanism to reduce size)

```
gzip /home/backup/backup_<timestamp>.sql
```

Comment: I am looking for an automatic solution, something I can set as a MySql Job to back up the database correctly and also make does a maintenance on the table.

Comment: [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-mysqldump.html) is the standard. Run it from a cron job and it is automatic.

Comment: What is a cron job? sorry I am new to this.

Comment: cron is a periodic task scheduler. please follow the link on how to set up a cron task : http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Comment: Thank you, My server is Windows 2008 R2 and not lunix. does corn still apply?

Comment: yes.. windows has similar mechanism to schedule a task to run periodically. please see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx